# IdentityServer3 - UserInfo endpoint gets invalid token

Tags: identityserver3

I'm new to IdentityServer3 and am just starting to get it set up.  It seems to be going quite well and I've been working on the Hybrid flow for an MVC app similar to that shown in Kevin Dockx's Pluralsight course (http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-securing-restful-api-aspdotnet)-- I'm using a custom user service.

The authentication from the MVC app to my identity server works great, but then when I call the userinfo endpoint I always get an Unauthorized, with Bearer on the response being "invalid token".

I'm passing in the access token I got back from the original OpenIdConnectAuthentication invocation, and it decodes in a JWT debugger to the following:

```
{
  "client_id": "mvc",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "actioncenter"
  ],
 "sub": "erik",
 "amr": "password",
 "auth_time": 1437591012,
 "idp": "idsrv",
 "iss": "https://id.local/",
 "aud": "https://id.local/resources",
 "exp": 1437594614,
 "nbf": 1437591014
}
```

I've also noticed that the response content comes back with something like "RunToCompletion".  I have downloaded the source from Github to see about the possibility of debugging and suspect that it is newer than the NuGet package that I'm running (1.6.2).

I suspect there is something I'm doing wrong, but I haven't been able to see it yet.  Any help would be appreciated.

I've included the code that I *think* is relevant.

From the ID Server:

```
static class Clients
{
    public static List<Client> Get()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {                
            new Client
            {
                ClientName = "MVC Client",
                ClientId = "mvc",
                Enabled = true,
                RequireConsent = true,

                RedirectUris = new List<string>     
                                   { "https://localhost:44300/" },
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,

                Flow = Flows.Hybrid,
                ScopeRestrictions = new List<string>()
                {
                    Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    Constants.StandardScopes.Profile,                       
                    "actioncenter"
                }

            }
        };
    }
static class Scopes
{
    public static List<Scope> Get()
    {
        return new List<Scope>
        {
            //identity scopes
            StandardScopes.OpenId,
            StandardScopes.Profile,
            //StandardScopes.EmailAlwaysInclude,
            //StandardScopes.PhoneAlwaysInclude,
            StandardScopes.Roles,

            //resource scopes
            new Scope
            {
                Name = "actioncenter",
                Type = ScopeType.Resource,
                Emphasize = false,
                Enabled = true,
                DisplayName = "Action Center"                    
            }
        };
    }
public class NwpIdentityUserService : IUserService
{
    public class CustomUser
    {
        public string Subject { get; set; }  // identifier for user
        public string Provider { get; set; } // provider name that did the auth for the user
        public string ProviderId { get; set; } // userid from the provider for this user
        public List<Claim> Claims { get; set; }
    }

    public Task<AuthenticateResult> PreAuthenticateAsync(SignInMessage message)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<AuthenticateResult>(null);
    }

    public Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateLocalAsync(string username, string password, SignInMessage message)
    {
        AuthenticateResult result;

        if (username != password)
            result = new AuthenticateResult("Invalid username/password");
        else
            result = new AuthenticateResult(username, "erik", new List<Claim> { new Claim("role", "writer") });

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }

    public Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateExternalAsync(ExternalIdentity externalUser, SignInMessage message)
    {
        //var ourUserId = GetOurUserId()
        // LOGIC:
        // From the information in externalUser, determine our user ID
        // Assuming valid, return a new authenticate result with the nwp user name, claims, etc.

        return Task.FromResult<AuthenticateResult>(null);
    }

    public Task SignOutAsync(ClaimsPrincipal subject)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetProfileDataAsync(ClaimsPrincipal subject, IEnumerable<string> requestedClaimTypes = null)
    {
        var nwpUserId = GetOurUserId(subject);
        if (nwpUserId == null)
            return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Claim>>(null);

        var claims = GetOurClaimsForUser(nwpUserId);
        return Task.FromResult(claims.Where(a => requestedClaimTypes.Contains(a.Type)));
    }

    private List<Claim> GetOurClaimsForUser(int? ourUserId)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim("role", "basicuser"));

        return claims;
    }

    public Task<bool> IsActiveAsync(ClaimsPrincipal subject)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(GetOurUserId(subject) != null);
    }

    private int? GetOurUserId(ClaimsPrincipal subject)
    {
        var userclaim = subject.Claims.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == "name");
        if (userclaim == null)
            return null;

        return 123;
    }
}
```

And the following is the pertinent code from the MVC client app - the response.StatusCode is always Unauthorized with the "invalid token" bearer message below:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "mvc",
            Authority = "https://id.local/identity/",
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300/",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            ResponseType = "code id_token token",
            Scope = "openid profile actioncenter",

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                MessageReceived = async n =>
                {
                    var userInfo = await GetUserInfoFromEndpoint(n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private async Task<JObject> GetUserInfoFromEndpoint(string accessToken)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);

        var response = await client.GetAsync("https://id.local/identity/connect/userinfo");

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JObject.Parse(json);
        }
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Additonal note:  I've actually seen in the debugger that I *hit* the GetProfileDataAsync call in my custom user service, and that it has one claim to return.  At that point, it's back to the framework and I get the 401.

Comment: Try to see the thinktecture log that should be found in output window if you use the default logger

Comment: Great tip, Ming!  I had a custom logger that I was using and hadn't really been scrutinizing the non-exception details.  As soon as I reviewed those, I discovered that the real root of the problem was that when the call to IsUserActiveAsync was made, the return value was false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon review of the Thinktecture logs as suggested by Ming, I discovered that the problem was that a call was being made by framework to IsUserActiveAsync, and that returned false due to a little bug in my mocked up code.  When I fixed that, everything started working.